# why a public constant string property in mvvmlight's default implementation?

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, inotifypropertychanged

I'm using mvvmlight and I find the default implementation (from code snippet of mvvminpcmsg) of an inpc is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="MyProperty" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string MyPropertyPropertyName = "MyProperty";

    private bool _myProperty = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the MyProperty property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// This property's value is broadcasted by the MessengerInstance when it changes.
    /// </summary>
    public bool MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myProperty;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_myProperty == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(MyPropertyPropertyName);
            var oldValue = _myProperty;
            _myProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(MyPropertyPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering why the public const string is added?

```
public const string MyPropertyPropertyName = "MyProperty";
```

I don't think it's required by inpc implementation nor I see any usage of it.
So why it's added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All INPC implementations need some way to resolve which property is raising the change notification. This is typically done by:

- Passing in the string name of the property
- Using an expression to resolve the property name
- Using the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

In your example, it is using a string name of the property.

Comment: but why it's `public`?

Comment: @Fei: No idea on that one.

Answer (score 1):

The public constant string for the property is added for scenarios where you're outside of the class but need to handle the property change event.